# Как работать с проектом в разных веб-окружениях?

Tags: php, linux, windows, phpstorm, openserver

У меня есть проект на опенсервере . И мне бы хотелось работать с этим проектом, но уже из под убунту, это реально? Что для этого нужно?
Допустим, lamp на убунте установлен.

Фишка такая, если у меня на компе стоит винда, то я буду работать из опенсервера, если убунту , то я буду работать так....
Вопрос в том, как я могу подгрузить проект из убунту, и что мне для этого нужно?

Comment: Использовать git

Comment: @robertobadjo, , как вы себе это представляете? Где гит должен лежать по Вашему, и где проект?

Comment: я хочу хранить проект на внешнем ЖД, и подключаться к нему из разных ОС.

Comment: Вы представляете что такое git? Создайте репозиторий c проектом, например на bitbucket, и синхронизуйте Ваш проект на различных ОС. Если хотите на жестком диске носить, то используйте vagrant. Но с различными ОС я не представляю как это будет работать.

Comment: @robertobadjo, спасибо, а если ,допустим, я не хочу выгружать на гитхаб, а гит находится у меня локально в проекте, присутствует папка .git в проекте